# Change time formatting of Firebase App Distribution builds

Tags: android, swift, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the way build date are shown in **App Distribution** app on the phone. It's kinda annoying that it's shown in **UTC**. It defeats the purpose of showing the time if we can't interpret in properly... Isn't there a setting where we can select the correct timezone?